# C# avoid cast when having inheritance chain

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I'm facing a problem right now that I don't know how to handle without casting

Imagine having a simple chat system with users (premium and classic)

You want to display a dashboard score but only scoring users must be displayed in since there are no score for regular users.

This is what I'm thinking of so far :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface IUser
{
    public string Id { get; }
}

interface IScoringUser : IUser
{
    public int Score { get; }
}

class ClassicUser : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; }
}

class PremiumUser : IScoringUser
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public int Score { get; }
}

class Chat
{
    public List<IUser> Users { get; } = new();

    public void JoinChat(IUser user)
    {
        Users.Add(user);
    }
}

class ChatScoreDashboard
{
    public void DisplayScore(Chat chat)
    {
        foreach (var user in chat.Users)
        {
            if (user is IScoringUser scoringUser)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(scoringUser.Score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I handle this without casting?

Maybe we could ask the user its scoring, but I do not want to have any trace of scoring in regular users since they are not eligible for this feature.

What about if we want to get **all scoring users?**

Are there some edge cases where casting is just required?

Comment: I wouldn’t use inheritance for this problem

Comment: you can use Linq's `OfType<T>()` to avoid the cast, but generally, you have a `List<IUser>`, which can be ... well, any type that implements that interface! There is no way to avoid some filtering or casting.

Comment: If you want to use inheritance, have both user types implement the same interface. In the premium user class's implementation, the scoring does something useful, in the plain user case, it doesn't. (you'll probably need to change the signature and semantics of your scoring, though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a family of heterogenously shaped data [you can always model it as a Visitor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type):

```
public interface IUser
{
    T Accept<T>(IUserVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public interface IUserVisitor<T>
{
    T Visit(ClassicUser user);
    T Visit(PremiumUser user);
}

public sealed record ClassicUser(string Id) : IUser
{
    public T Accept<T>(IUserVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public sealed record PremiumUser(string Id, int Score) : IUser
{
    public T Accept<T>(IUserVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

No casting is required to extract only the premium users from a collection of `IUser` objects:

```
public static class ChatScoreDashboard
{
    public static IEnumerable<PremiumUser> GetPremiumUsers(IEnumerable<IUser> users)
    {
        return users.Aggregate(
            Enumerable.Empty<PremiumUser>(),
            (acc, user) => acc.Concat(user.Accept(new PremiumUserVisitor())));
    }

    private sealed class PremiumUserVisitor : IUserVisitor<IEnumerable<PremiumUser>>
    {
        public IEnumerable<PremiumUser> Visit(ClassicUser user)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<PremiumUser>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<PremiumUser> Visit(PremiumUser user)
        {
            return new[] { user };
        }
    }
}
```

The following test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void GetScores()
{
    var users = new IUser[]
    {
        new ClassicUser("1"),
        new PremiumUser("2", 42),
        new ClassicUser("3"),
        new PremiumUser("4", 1337)
    };

    var actual = ChatScoreDashboard.GetPremiumUsers(users);

    var expected = new[]
    {
        new PremiumUser("2", 42),
        new PremiumUser("4", 1337)
    };
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

You can now iterate over the collection returned by `GetPremiumUsers` if you, for example, want to display that list to a user. Again, no casting is required, since you have a collection of `PremiumUser` objcets, which do have the `Score` property.

If you think it's too awkward having to define explicit Visitor classes, you can instead model the alternative types with [Church encoding](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/22/church-encoding). These two representations are isomorphic.

Whether that's *actually* the most appropriate way to model your problem domain is another question, but I don't have enough context to address such questions.